# Absolutely continuous and differentiable almost everywhere

Tags: integration, derivatives, bochner-spaces, absolute-continuity

I've read the following claim and I wonder if someone can direct me to or provide me with a proof of it:

> "A strongly absolutely continuous function which is differentiable
>   almost everywhere is the indefinite integral of strongly integrable
>   derivative"

It was in the context of Bochner integrable functions so I'm assuming that "strongly" means with respect to the norm.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An absolute continuous function $f:[a,b] \to X$ is differentiable almost everywhere such that for a fixed $y \in [a,b]$

$$f(x) = \int_x^y f'(z) \, \text{d} z + f(y) \quad \text{for all } x \in [a,b].$$

In particular $f'$ is strongly integrable, i.e. $f' \in L^1(a,b;X)$.

You can find this in the book "Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions" by Evans and Gariepy. Also in the book "Linear Functional Analysis" by Alt.